# React/Redux - onKeyPress also fires onBlur

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React with Redux application with a form. This form does a look-up of what the user entered as the user fills out the form via the `onBlur` attribute. If the user presses the Enter key via `onKeyPress`, the same look-up action is performed.

When this look-up fails, an error shows up on screen. However, when the user presses the Enter key, two errors show up: one for the `onKeyPress` and one for the `onBlur`.  How do I prevent the `onBlur` from firing if the `onKeyPress` has fired?

My sample code:

```
<TextFieldComponent
    placeholder="Type in text here"
    value={this.props.text}
    onBlur={() => this.props.validation()}
    onKeyPress={() => this.props.validation()}
>
```

Comment: You could check `e.keyCode != 13` on the onBlur event.

Comment: @GavinBruce I tried `onBlur={(e) => if (e.keyCode != 13) { this.props.validation() }}` but that didn't work either.  Pressing the enter key still triggers both the `onKeyPress` and `onBlur`

Answer (score 0):

onBlur will not fire onKeyPress but only when input lose focus.

If you don't want to validate on the same input twice, then you should keep tracking of your input value, and validate only if value is changed.